# HELP four forms files lost into subversion!

Tags: svn, visual-studio-2010, ankhsvn

so i decided to finally try out subversion with Ankh SVN for Visual studio 2010, after my nasty experiences with VSS.

I installed CollabNet SVN on my win7 dev box and then Ankh SVN for VS2010.

(Like an Idiot) I added a mockup demo project I was working on and played around with it using SVN. After a while, I un installed Office 2007 (long story) and my solution has references to office interop COM objects.

So there were some errors in the project, after I removed the references and fixed it all, suddenly all my form cs files are missing. The designer and the resx files are still there, but all the forms show up with a little error icon on them!!

I tried revert to different revisions (I only made 5 revs) I tried exporting it says "this is not a working copy" !! The files are missing from the solution directly itself!! I also removed the ref to subversion in a copy of the solution and placed all the files in another directory and turned off Ankh SVN in VS but the files are just GONE!!

I spent 3 days on the forms and I have to give the demo sometime this week!!

Gideon

Comment: Have you tried making a fresh checkout of a new workspace yet? I am hoping you had committed all your local changes into the svn repo, and if so you can take a clean workspace.

Comment: still completely new to the whole source versioning thing, dont quite get what you're saying. Can you tell me how I can do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, I have no idea what could have cause the files to be deleted from your disk.

What you can do to see if they're somewhere in your repository is use View -> Repository Explorer. If your repository doesn't show up there, use the icon with the '+' to add it. Then right click the root, and select View History. Browse through all 5 revisions you created and see if you see the .cs files there somewhere.

Comment: nope the files are just completely GONE! I did a search for them on my whole computer, I also went into the repository.
Finally I just had to do all the work again! But I'm really hesitant about using SVN now! =( Would it be safer/better to use tortoisesvn instead of Ankh.

Comment: ok I did another test with a dummy solution. I made 10 revisions committed each of them. Then I right clicked the solution and chose View Solution history. I right clicked version7 and selected revert to this version, BOOM, all my files have a red X on them and when I click them its says they're gone. Also, they're all deleted from my folder!

Comment: If you revert to a revision that doesn't contain the files, they get removed from your working copy indeed. That doesn't mean they're gone though. You can revert the working copy to get them back, try right-clicking the solution and selecting "Revert" from there, and then update

Comment: You can also see in the repository explorer that the files that were removed are there.

Comment: nope, I tried practically every option. I also, un installed everything then re installed, then added a project to source control, committed a few changes and then reverted and same thing happens, some files just go missing. They have a yellow information triangle icon instead of the regular icons for cs files in the solution explorer.I'm sure I made a screw up somewhere during maybe the SVN installation, but I think it would be just better to move on and find something else.

Comment: Can you at least try to give a reproduction of the problem, so we can fix the bug (if any)?

Comment: ok I will. I'll note everything I did this time the post it back here.

Comment: Im a little confused, once I commit a few versions, if I want to revert to a specific version, what do I do? I open the history viewer and right click the version I want to revert to and then select "Revert to this Revision" All files have a red exclamation mark now and when I update these files with changes and try to commit it says "trying to commit conflicted items"? I can resolve all files by right clicking and selecting resolve, but the solution still has a red mark and I cannot resolve it?

Comment: I tried to branch a solution and all my subfolders where then empty and I now have to manually replace all of the local files from the server to re-add them.  Ankhsvn is terrible buggy and this is with the latest client-plugin for visual studio 2008 as of 24 April 2013.